# Different CSS styles for each HTML tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

Developing a website using Django (irrelevant, really), and have been toying with the implementation of tabs versus a navbar, as I want certain pages to update when selected without completely redirecting to a new page, or refreshing it entirely. For this to be useful, however, each tab would require its own format of CSS, as each page that's being displayed is inherently different from every other (lets say there are 4 tabs, each tab would display completely different page, ranging from an image library to just text); this is required as I need the banner to remain fixed at the top of the page, as well as the position of the user on said page to remain the same once a new tab is selected, or at least not have the page reload. My question is, how would this theoretically be done, as I have found very little documentation on the matter, other than people claiming "its possible" when asked.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" name="css-tabs" id="tab-1" checked class="tab-switch">
      <label for="tab-1" class="tab-label">Tab One</label>
      <div class="tab-content">sample text</div>
    </div>
```

Based on the input above, I would assume you could list multiple entries and modify each one using the id="tab-1" modifier within CSS, something similar to #tab-1, #tab-2, #tab-3, to update each selection individually, however, this does not seem to work when attempted. I have also attempted to incorporate separate CSS files, which would be the optimal result, however, they do not seem to load properly when incorporated, and I have found little documentation on implementing multiple CSS files in the way that is required for differential tabs.

(Alternatively, is there a way to obtain this format using a navbar, whereas instead of a link to a separate page, it displays the change within the body, similar to a tab modifying its container; ultimately, I want the display to be similar to that of a navbar.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "*[However], this does not seem to work when attempted.*" - can you show your attempts? I believe we may have answers that can help.

Comment: Well, that's not how you target an element by ID with CSS. Have you done some reading?

Comment: Tabs don't update when selected. Everything is already there unless you use some mechanism to perform updates. Your question is quite vague (see [ask]), but you may want to look into something like React, which is often used to develop single-page applications like you describe.

Comment: @isherwood I've looked into targeting ID elements using CSS and I haven't found anything that has worked as of yet. I would display more example code, except I've primarily executed the backend for the website, and am just now beginning the front, and this question is the primary concern for the first page. I will look into React to see if its a better fit, but if possible I'd like to remain using Django, thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Django is on the server. React is in the browser. They're not exclusive (thought you wouldn't normally use Django routing with a React app).

Comment: @isherwood I'm aware of that, I just didn't want to have to bother implementing React if not necessary for what I need, however, I'll look into it anyway considering how much faster it is than libraries like jQuery and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `div` to put your content in them. After that, you can hide your `div` with `display: none;`.

You can now, with Javascript, change the display of one of your `div` that contains your content.You can use the `document.getElementById('div-1').style.display = "initial"` to show one of your tab and you can use the `document.getElementById('div-1').style.display = "none"` to hide it.

Here is an example that I have found on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/):
[Example of the tab switching](https://codepen.io/marsojane/pen/WvbKaw)

```js
function hideOtherTabs(tabList, tab, tabPrefix){
    
    for (index = 0; index < tabList.length; index++) {
        if(tabPrefix+tab!=tabPrefix+tabList[index]){
            $('div#'+tabPrefix+tabList[index]).hide();
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready( function(){
 
    var tabPrefix = 'home_';
    var tabs = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3'];
    
    for (index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
        jQuery('div#'+tabPrefix+tabs[index]).hide();
    }
        
    jQuery('ul.tab_links li').click( function(){
         
        var tabID = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert(tabID);
        //show this tab
        jQuery('div#'+tabPrefix+tabID).show();
        
        //hide others
        hideOtherTabs(tabs,tabID,tabPrefix);
    });
});
```

```css
.tab_links {}

.tab_links li {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #B326DA;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab_links li:hover {
  background: #D746FF;
}

.tab_box{
  min-height: 200px;
  width:335px;
  margin: 10px 0 5px 40px;
  border:1px dashed #B326DA;
  padding:10px;
  
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #B326DA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<ul class='tab_links'>
  <li id='tab1'>Tab 1</li>
  <li id='tab2'>Tab 2</li>
  <li id='tab3'>Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<div class='tab_box' id='home_tab1'>
  Crazy world tab1
</div>
<div class='tab_box' id='home_tab2'>
  Hello world tab2
</div>
<div class='tab_box' id='home_tab3'>
  Bye world tab3
</div>
```

Comment: I can modify this to make it work for what's required, thanks.